# is it possible to create Feathersjs Oauth with apple sign in?

Tags: react-native, apple-sign-in, feathers-authentication

I am trying to integrate my React Native Ios project with feathers js. If my apps has any social login, it is required to have Apple Sign In method to be included to the project in order to publish to the store.

Comment: any success on this?

Answer (score 2):

About a year late, but I finally figured out FeathersJS + Apple Oauth this weekend and created a guide:

https://gist.github.com/rxb/e596c66b03e3262f26d9ede5d7dbab81